# How to get rid of the word optional before a url saved in firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Currently I am saving the url of images stored in the firebase database. However I am getting the word optional before the url. As seen bellow.

> "Optional(https:URL.HERE)"

The following is the code block where the saving happens:

```
if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) {
    let metadata = storageRef //.child("poop/")

    let uploadTask = metadata.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        guard let metadata = metadata else {
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            return
        }

        // You can also access to download URL after upload.
        storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            guard let downloadURL = url else {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                return
            }
            let imgURL = url

            //database integration
            let ref = Database.database().reference()
            let usersRef = ref.child("usersPosts")

            let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            let newUserRef = usersRef.child(uid!)
            //creates a child for email and password (i think we shud store password so we can tell sumone what it is inmediatly, maybe)
            newUserRef.setValue(["Image": "\(imgURL)"])
        }

    }

    // For progress
    uploadTask.observe(.progress, handler: { (snapshot) in
        guard let progress = snapshot.progress else {
            return
        }

        let percentage = (Float(progress.completedUnitCount) / Float(progress.totalUnitCount))
        progressBlock(Double(percentage))
    })

} else {
    completionBlock(nil, "Image could not be converted to Data.")
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting `Optional...` because `imgURL` is optional. And `imgURL` is optional because you assigned it from `url` which is optional.

Since you already unwrapped `url` in the `guard` statement, just use `downloadURL` instead of creating `imgURL`.

Remove:

```
let imgURL = url
```

And replace the use of `imgURL` with `downloadURL` which is the properly unwrapped version of `url` from the `guard`.

```
newUserRef.setValue(["Image": "\(downloadURL)"])
```